# How to cut out unnecessary extra coding for CSS/HTML and make it more responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tumblr, tumblr-html

Afternoon all ( or evening/morning/night ). I'm looking a slight push in the right direction regarding a project of mine. This layout is for tumblr ( not an actual page for a company so please don't yell at me ), and it's my first code that I've managed to make. The problem is that right after making it, I noticed how... poorly it was made. I use too much padding, margins, and other nonsense that could be cut out.

I desperately wanted to try and rewrite the code, using percentages, rems/ems, vh/vw, etc while still keeping the layout/design 100% intact. The problem, however, is that I wouldn't know how to begin, exactly, or what to even cut out, while still keeping the spacing and such intact. For example, say I want to completely eliminate pixel measurements for my post container ( .pc ), how do I ensure it remains in that same exact spot ( at least on screens that share my same viewport measurement ) with those margins, while using say, percentages? How do I even measure a div container in percentages or even vw/vh to begin with?

Please know that I'm not trying to have someone do this for me, or anything like that. I just want to have a nudge in the proper direction where I can start. Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/q5cFtVQP and a snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
 
<!-- BROWSER TITLE -->
<title> .</title>
<!-- END OF BROWSER TITLE -->
 
<!-- BROWSER ICON -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://66.media.tumblr.com/e948812964cb16505f4cd4f894344288/672e88b582120b94-84/s540x810/9301ad0a7a1dc0235256ca2aa89738258b0383a5.png">
<!-- END OF BROWSER ICON -->
 
<!-- FONTS -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bowlby+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,900,700,700italic,500italic,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- END OF FONTS -->
 
<style type="text/css">
 
/* PULSE ANIMATION */
.pulsate { -webkit-animation: pulsate 2s ease-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
opacity: 0.5; }
   
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate { 0% { opacity: 0.5; }
50% { opacity: 1.0;}
100% { opacity: 0.5; } }
/* END OF PULSE ANIMATION */
 
/* FOLLOW BUTTONS */
.iframe-controls--desktop { position:fixed;
top:0px;
right:0px;
z-index:214748364789123456789;
-filter:invert(100%);
-webkit-filter:invert(100%);  
-webkit-transform:scale(0.6,0.6);
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
-ms-transform-origin:100% 0%;
-ms-transform:scale(0.6,0.6);
transform:scale(0.6,0.6);
 transform-origin:100% 0%; }
/* END OF FOLLOW BUTTONS */
 
/* SELECTION */
::selection { background:#ff40f3; }
::-moz-selection { background:#ff40f3; }
/* END OF SELECTION */
 
/* SCROLLBAR */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background:#ff62f5;
border-radius:25px;linear-gradient(to bottom, #b1e0f5 , #ffc4f6);
width:8px;
height:5px; }
 
::-webkit-scrollbar { background:#292929;
border-radius:25px;
height:5px;
width:8px; }
/* END OF SCROLLBAR */
 
/* EMBEDS */
embed, object, video { max-width: 200px; }
 
img { max-width:180px;
height:auto;
width:auto; }
/* END OF EMBEDS */
 
/* BLOG STYLINGS */
html { background-color:#e6eaeb;
color:#e6eaeb;
font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
text-align:left;
word-spacing:3px;
text-transform:uppercase; }
 
.tc a:hover, .nav a:hover, .pagc a:hover,#mybtn:hover { cursor: pointer;
color: #ff62f5;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out; }
 
.posts a:hover, .pnc a:hover { color: #ff62f5;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out; }
 
.divider { border-top: 6px solid #02afff;
border-radius:5px;
margin:auto;
width:80%; }
 
pre, small, sup, sub { font-size:1rem;
font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; }
 
blockquote { border-left:4px solid;
color:#ff62f5;
padding-left:5px;
margin-left:3px;
width:94%; }
       
blockquote p { font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
color:#efefef; }
       
blockquote blockquote { margin-left:1px; }
 
h3 { text-transform:uppercase;
color:#ff62f5;
text-align:center;
font-family:'Bowlby One', cursive;
font-size:1.5rem;
letter-spacing:1px; }
 
h1, h2 { color:#02afff;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:25px;
padding-bottom:2px;
font-family:'Bowlby One', cursive;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:2rem;
margin-top:10px;
margin-right:15px;
background-color:#313131;
box-shadow: 0 -4px #ff62f5 inset; }
 
p { font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; }
       
b, strong { color:#02afff; }
       
i { color:#ff62f5;
font-style:normal; }
/* END OF BLOG STYLINGS */
 
/* READ MORE BUTTON */
#more { color:#e6eaeb;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
font-family:'Bowlby One', cursive;
font-size:1rem;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
padding:2px;
background-color:#ff62f5;
border-radius:25px; }
 
#more:hover { color:#02afff;
cursor: pointer; }
/* END OF READ MORE BUTTON */
 
/* SCROLL TO TOP BUTTON */
#stt { position: fixed; /* Fixed/sticky position */
z-index:99999999999999;
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
top:613px; /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
left:1029px; /* Place the button 30px from the right */
border: none; /* Remove borders */
outline: none; /* Remove outline */
font-family:'Bowlby One', cursive;
background-color: #02afff; /* Set a background color */
color:#e6eaeb;
cursor: pointer; /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
padding:6px;
border-radius:15px; /* Rounded corners */
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
font-size:1rem; /* Increase font size */ }
/* END OF SCROLL TO TOP BUTTON */
 
/* PERMALINK PAGE */
.permc { margin-top:5px;
margin-left:18px;
left:368px;
width:387px;
max-height:220px;
background-color:#252525;
overflow-x:hidden;
border-left:25px solid #ff62f5; }
 
.permc p, .permc a { color:#ff62f5;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:0px;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
font-family:'Bowlby One', cursive;
font-size:1rem;
text-transform:uppercase; }
 
.permc img.avatar { display:none; }
 
.permc li { list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0; }
/* END OF PERMALINK PAGE */
 
/* MAIN TITLE */
.mtc { margin-top:45px;
margin-bottom:45px;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
left:385px;
width:648px;
height:96px;
background-color:#252525;
border-left:25px solid #ff62f5;
padding:0 -15px -40px 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.39); }
 
.mt { font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
color:#e6eaeb;
text-indent:20px;
font-size:5.9rem;
text-shadow:3px 5px 1px #6bb6fa; }
/* END OF MAIN TITLE */
 
/* POSTS */
.pc { position:absolute;
padding-top:98px;
padding-bottom:6px;
top:14px;
left:368px;
width:445px;
min-height:450px;
margin-bottom:15px;
background-color:#313131;
border-top:15px solid #02afff;
border-bottom:15px solid #02afff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.39); }
 
.posts { width:375px;
font-weight:900;
max-height:350px;
min-height:150px;
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:18px;
padding-left:10px;
left:368px;
background-color:#252525;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
border-left:25px solid #ff62f5; }
 
.posts a { text-decoration:none;
box-shadow:0 -4px #ff62f5 inset;
font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
color:#02afff;
padding-bottom:5px;
font-size:1rem; }
/* END OF POSTS */
 
/* POST TITLE */
.ptc { width:375px;
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:18px;
padding-left:10px;
left:368px;
background-color:#252525;
border-left:25px solid #ff62f5; }
 
.pt { color:#e6eaeb;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:35px;
padding-bottom:5px;
font-family:'Bowlby One', cursive;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:2.8rem;
padding-top:5px;
margin-right:15px;
text-shadow:3px 3px 1px #6bb6fa }
/* END OF POST TITLE */
 
/* POST TAGS */
.tc { width:367px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
margin-left:18px;
margin-top:5px;
background-color:#252525;
border-left:25px solid #ff62f5; }
 
.tc a { color:#e6eaeb;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
font-family:'Bowlby One', cursive;
font-size:1rem;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
padding:4px;
background-color:#02afff;
border-radius:25px; }
/* END OF POST TAGS */
 
/* NAVIGATION CONTAINER + NAVIGATION */
.navc { position:fixed;
top:547px;
left:818px;
width:242px;
min-height:32px;
background-color:#313131;
border-top:15px solid #02afff;
border-bottom:15px solid #02afff; }
 
.nav { display:inline block;
width:67px;
float:left;
height:24px;
margin-top:4px;
margin-left:2px;
background-color:#252525;
border-left:10px solid #ff62f5; }
 
.nav a { text-decoration:none;
font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
color:#e6eaeb;
text-align:center;
font-size:1.3rem;
margin-left:4px;
margin-top:3px;
text-shadow:2px 1px 1px #0081bd; }
/* END OF NAVIGATION */
 
/* PAGINATION */
.pagc { position:fixed;
top:613px;
left:818px;
max-width:148px;
height:15px;
padding:7px;
background-color:#02afff;
border-radius:25px; }
 
.pagc a { color:#e6eaeb;
font-size:.9rem;
text-decoration:none;
font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive; }
/* END OF PAGINATION */
 
/* SIDEBAR 1 + CONTAINER */
.sbc1 { position:fixed;
top:155px;
left:818px;
width:242px;
height:327px;
background-color:#313131;
border-top:15px solid #02afff;
border-bottom:15px solid #02afff;
overflow-y:auto;
z-index:1; }
 
.sb1 { margin-right:10px;
margin-left:10px;
font-weight:900; }
/* END OF SIDEBAR 1 + CONTAINER */
 
/* POSTNOTES */
.pnc { width:250px;
height:45px;
background-color:#252525;
padding-left:10px;
margin-left:18px;
line-height:2.8;
margin-top:35px;
border-left:25px solid #ff62f5; }
 
.pnc a { text-decoration:none;
color:#02afff;
font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
font-size:.9rem;
display:inline-block;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
box-shadow:0 -4px #ff62f5 inset; }
/* END OF POSTNOTES CONTAINER */
 
/* MODAL POPUP */
 
/* MODAL OPEN BUTTON */
#mybtn { width:242px;
position:fixed;
height:26px;
background-color:#02afff;
border:none;
top:516px;
left:818px;
font-size:1.6rem;
color:#e6eaeb;
font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive; }
 
button:focus { outline: none; }
/* END OF MODAL OPEN BUTTON */
 
/* MODAL BOX */
.modal { display:none; /* Hidden by default */
position:fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index:9999999999999999999; /* Sit on top */
padding-top:50px; /* Location of the box */
left:0;
top:0;
overflow-y:auto;
width:100%; /* Full width */
height:100%;
background-color:rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.95); /* Black w/ opacity */ }
/* END OF MODAL BOX */
 
/* MODAL CONTENT */
.modal-content { position: relative;
background-color: #313131;
margin:auto;
overflow-y:auto;
padding:0;
border-top:15px solid #02afff;
border-bottom:15px solid #02afff;
width:680px;
max-height:85%;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
-webkit-animation-name:zoom;
-webkit-animation-duration:0.4s;
animation-name:zoom;
animation-duration: 0.4s }
 
.modal-body { padding: 5px 26px;
font-size:1rem;
font-weight:900;
color:#e6eaeb; }
/* END OF MODAL CONTENT */
 
/* MODAL ANIMATION */
@keyframes zoom {0% {transform: scale(1,1);}
50% {transform: scale(1.2,1.2);}
100% {transform: scale(1,1);} }
/* END OF MODAL ANIMATION */
 
/* MODAL CLOSE BUTTON */
.close { color:#e6eaeb;
width:85px;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:'Bowlby One', cursive;
font-size:1rem;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:2%;
padding:4px;
background-color:#02afff;
border-radius:25px; }
 
.close:hover { cursor: pointer;
color: #ff62f5;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;  }
/* END OF MODAL CLOSE BUTTON */
 
/* END OF MODAL POPUP */
 
/* SVG GRAPHICS */
/* BOTTOM WAVE */
#wave { position:fixed;
z-index:-100;
width:100%;
bottom:-3px;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
left: 0px;
right: 0px; }
/* END OF BOTTOM WAVE */
 
/* RIGHT BLOB */
#blob1 {position:fixed;
margin:auto;
left:860px;
top:80px;
bottom:0px;
width:500px;
height:515px;
overflow: hidden; }
 
#blob1stroke {position:fixed;
margin:auto;
stroke:#ffa6f9;
stroke-width:1px;
transform:rotate(10deg);
left:860px;
top:80px;
bottom:0px;
width:500px;
height:515px;
overflow: hidden; }
/* END OF RIGHT BLOB */
 
/* LEFT BLOB */
#blob2 { position:fixed;
margin:auto;
left:50px;
top:-80px;
z-index:-2;
bottom:0px;
width:500px;
height:515px;
overflow: hidden; }
 
#blob2stroke { position:fixed;
margin:auto;
left:50px;
top:-80px;
z-index:-2;
stroke:#ffa6f9;
stroke-width:1px;
transform:rotate(10deg);
bottom:0px;
width:500px;
height:515px;
overflow: hidden; }
/* END OF LEFT BLOB */
 
</style>
```

( here's a live demo, if that matters: https://kittycodes-preview.tumblr.com/ )

Any help is appreciated! ( note: before anyone wants to point out the 'incorrect' layout; Tumblr is very unorthodox with its' coding layout setup. The css and html go together and use exclusive blocks for posts and such, and it would actually look broken if you try to deploy the code in of itself ).

Answer (score 0):

> I use too much padding, margins, and other nonsense that could be cut
> out.

Why do you think that padding and margins are nonsense? What is the "other" nonsense you're referring to? I've never built a website or a view in a web application that didn't use padding and margin to some extent.

> I desperately wanted to try and rewrite the code, using percentages,
> rems/ems, vh/vw, etc while still keeping the layout/design 100%
> intact.

Is this because you read a medium article that said you should use those units? Different units are useful in different situations.

> For example, say I want to completely eliminate pixel measurements for
> my post container ( .pc ), how do I ensure it remains in that same
> exact spot ( at least on screens that share my same viewport
> measurement ) with those margins, while using say, percentages?

Why do you need to eliminate pixel measurements? There's nothing inherently wrong with pixels. It depends on the situation and what you're trying to accomplish.

> How do I even measure a div container in percentages or even vw/vh to
> begin with?

Honestly it seems like you haven't done any reading or made much of an effort to eduacate yourself. These are extremely basic things you're asking and you're going to have a much easier time finding the answers yourself by just learning how to write code. That being said you  measure a div in percentages the same way you measure anything in percentages...100% is the entirety...50% is half...etc.

I could see why view port units versus percentages could cause a little confusion.

`width: 100vw` is equal to 100% of the width of the users' screen.

`width: 100%` is equal to 100% of the element's parent's width.

I suggest you start somewhere like w3schools.com to start building a basic foundation of knowledge you need to answer the questions that you have.